# One character representations for words(rarely used characters)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character, symbols

I would like to use one character to represent a word for a chrome extension. So the code could look like this:

```
x.replace(/character/g,"a");
```

well, when I try to use a character/symbol in that spot, it gives me an error saying that the js is not utf-8. I need to use a one character/symbol representation for what I'm doing or it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you show us the exact code that gives you the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by saying “to use one character to represent a word for a chrome extension”, and what does the parenthetic note “rarely used characters” have to do with this? Are you looking for a character that you could use as a wildcard character that stands for any word (for some definition of “word”), or what?

Comment: I need 1 character/symbol to represent one letter. So let's say $ = a % = b @ = c, etc.. I would need rarely used characters/symbols because I am replacing them. with replace().

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be regex? You could just do:

```
x.replace('b', 'a');
```

Comment: Well I have to replace more than one instance of said character, I'm also looking for a solution to use just one symbol that will be utf-8 safe?